# Another GET called before a promise method execution in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular7, angular-http

I am new with angular 7 and facing a problem that I can't figure out why it's happening.

I want after every redirection **RouteGuard** will check if the token is valid or not. For that, I wrote the following service;

```
 getUserClaims():Promise<any> {
    /*return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._http.get(ALCA_Utility.API_BASE_URL + 'User/GetCurrentUser')
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { // Success

            resolve(res)
          }
        );
    });*/

     return this._http.get(ALCA_Utility.API_BASE_URL + 'User/GetCurrentUser')
       .toPromise();
  }
```

I tried both approaches, *(I comment out the above approach, and also I use `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` to intercept HTTP calls and add the token in the Authorization header)*.

The `canActive` method is bellow;

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {

      this._auth.getUserClaims().then((data) => {
        if (data.PK_UserID != null && data.PK_UserID > 0) {
          alert(1)

          return true
        }
        else{
          alert(2)      
          return false
        }
        alert(3)      

      })
      alert(4)      
    }
    else {      
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I thought the methods will execute in sequence in `canActive`, however, it is showing alert 4 then 1, 2, 3.

I don't understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

it's an asynchronous call when you do http.get within a promise.   for me its normal you see first 4, and then the rest.   you get a "promise" that somewhere in time you might or might not get answer back from the call.  In your program i don't really see the need to have the alert 4.  the only thing you could do there is to catch for errors

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below implementation :

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return userService.isAuthenticated().then(result => {
      if (result) return true;
      UserLoginService.setPreviousUrl(state.url);
      this.router.navigate(['login']);

      return false;
    }).catch(message => {
      userService.setPreviousUrl(state.url);
      this.router.navigate(['login']);

      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

for your case check the below :

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
      return this._auth.getUserClaims().then(data => {
        if (data.PK_UserID != null && data.PK_UserID > 0) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Please pay attention to the return type of canActivate

```
Promise<boolean> | boolean
```